# Javascript - Displaying browser details in new document

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create a button that will display browser details in a new document using javascript. I have searched here and w3schools and am quite stumped! I am really new to javascript so any advice is greatly appreciated. Thanks!

```
  <html>
  <head>
  <script  type="text/javascript">
  function docOpen()
   {
     document.open();
     document.write(browserDetails);
   }
 function browserDetails () {
  var  x = navigator
  document.write("CodeName=" +  x.appCodeName)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("MinorVersion=" +  x.appMinorVersion)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("Name=" +  x.appName)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("Version=" +  x.appVersion)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("CookieEnabled=" +  x.cookieEnabled)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("CPUClass=" +  x.cpuClass)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("OnLine=" +  x.onLine)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("Platform=" +  x.platform)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("UA=" +  x.userAgent)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("BrowserLanguage=" +  x.browserLanguage)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("SystemLanguage=" +  x.systemLanguage)
  document.write("<br  />")
  document.write("UserLanguage=” +  x.userLanguage)
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
  <input  type="button"  onclick="docOpen()"  value="Get Browser Details">
  </form>
  </body>
```

Comment: W3schools recommends bad practices like `document.write` (see the warning in [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/webappapis.html#document.write%28%29)). I suggest avoiding both.

Comment: Thanks Oriol. I was given the document.write  as an example by my college professor. This doesn't bode well for the class. lol

Answer (score 2):

You have a curly double quote in place of a normal (straight) double quote here:

```
document.write("UserLanguage=” +  x.userLanguage)
                             ^
```

This is causing a syntax error. Replace it with a straight quote.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you aren't invoking either of the functions you've defined. The call to `browserDetails` isn't a call, it's just a reference, and nothing is invoking the `docOpen` function.

Change line 4 to `document.write(browserDetails());`

Then invoke docOpen `docOpen()`

You'll also need to fix the smart quote as instructed by duskwuff.

I made a working fiddle at: https://jsfiddle.net/87q1a0kn/

Comment: `browserDetails()` doesn't return anything, it doesn't make sense to pass it as an argument.

Comment: It doesn't return anything because it writes to the document. It still needs to be invoked

Comment: Yes, it needs to be invoked, but not as an argument to `document.write()`. Just do `browserDetails();`.

Comment: Sure, but it's the minimum viable change from the OP to working code. The path of least resistance

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like

```
 <html>
  <head>
      <script>
  function docOpen()
   {
     document.open();
     document.write(browserDetails()); // ADD '()' to call the function
   }
 function browserDetails () {
    var  x = navigator;
    // iterate through all properties and get the values
    for(var prop in x) {
      document.write(prop+' = '+ x[prop]+'<br />');
    }
  }
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <form>
  <input  type="button"  onclick="docOpen()"  value="Get Browser Details">
  </form>
  </body>
```

**EDIT** based on @Barmar comment

```
<script>
  function docOpen()
   {
     document.open();
     browserDetails(); // ADD '()' to call the function -- 
   }
 function browserDetails () {
    var  x = navigator;
    // iterate through all properties and get the values
    for(var prop in x) {
      document.write(prop+' = '+ x[prop]+'<br />');
    }
  }
  </script>
```

Comment: `browserDetails()` doesn't return anything, it doesn't make sense to write the return value.